# Allow scrolling and clicking to go through an overlapping Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

A client's website design is dark teal and he didn't like the scroll bar since it ruins the rest of the style. He also wishes I do it without third party libraries and a way he can hopefully understand. So the only way I can think of doing that was creating a div, setting it to `position: absolute;`, same background-color as the rest of the theme and then setting `opacity: 0.8;` so that it looks 'blended' in better.

He is happy with the result, since it works for all browsers, he thought I even created my own scroll-bar when he first saw it. The problem however is, if a person would like to actually click on the scroll bar, they can't because there's a div above it. Is there any way I can allow a div to be visible, but all the clicks and hovers and everything go through it to the next div? Scrolling also does not work when above the scroll bar because i'm in the div that's overlapping the real div that actually has the scroll bar.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Added image to show what I mean, the scroll-bar just has a div above it to 'blend' it in with the rest of the environment, but when you mouse over the scroll-bar it does all the actions to the div that is overlapping it, making the scroll-bar not work anymore till you go back in it's actual div.

Edit2: Updated image

[image]

Comment: Don't see any reason for a downvote. Code would help, but custom-colored scrollbar is an interesting challenge.

Comment: I would gladly provide code but all the code would be is a div that has absolute position to be placed exactly above the scroll-bar with an opacity of 0.8, so it 'blends' the scroll-bar with the rest of the design. I could do a jsfiddle if my explanation doesn't make sense? Thanks for your help

Comment: I added a fiddle in my answer for what I assumed your code to be. Maybe it will help you brainstorm other approaches that will provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the answer you're hoping for, but I don't think it's possible to have the color overlay persist on the scrollbar and have it function in all browsers.

Setting `z-index: -1` on the background does what you want in Chrome, but in Firefox the scrollbar remains white.

http://jsfiddle.net/LrEpm/1/

Firefox shown below. In Chrome, the scrollbar disappears when not in use and remains functional with the teal background

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. The reason why z-index wouldn't work is because it would just place the div that's currently overlapping, behind the scroll-bar div, thus making the scroll-bar back to the bright white color that 'ruins' the rest of the design color, making no point in the overlapping div to begin with. I hope I'm making sense, sorry for the trouble

Comment: Sorry, you already said it wouldn't work. But this doesn't do what I want in Chrome either?

Comment: Pasted what I'm seeing in Chrome -- seems to be what you're after if I understand correctly.

Comment: That's odd, doesnt look like that for me in my Chrome. Still, the problem is there are way too many Firefox users to ignore :( I know Chrome even has custom scroll-bar css that allows you to create your own style completely, but firefox has no support from the many threads that I've read and tried. I believe even IE has support for it, well they were the first to have support for it from what I read, although now it might be deprecated. Still, I can't thank you enough for all your help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in CSS and apply it to whatever element you want to be able to click through...

```
.avoid-clicks { pointer-events: none; }
```

- **pointer-events: none** prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element
- **pointer-events: inherit** will use the pointer-events value of the element's parent
- **pointer-events: auto** restores the default functionality.